# Laravel edit dropzone

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I saved files(images) by [DropzoneJS](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dropzone) and I can get them everywhere I like, but my problem is how to edit them. I go to my products edit page I can see my image but have no idea how to edit them such as (delete some of them or add to them)

here is my code to get them:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      $images = DB::table('images')->where('imageable_id', '=', $product->id)->get();
// rest of codes
}
```

and I show my images in edit page like:

```
@foreach($images as $test)
  <img src="{{url('/')}}/images/{{$test->name}}" alt="test" width="100" height="100">
@endforeach
```

`screenshot`

[image: screen1]

## UPDATE

@linktoahref way works for me if I want to delete each of images, and he suggested to make new uploader for adding images into my product on edit page, `not bad idea totally` but it's not what I'm exactly looking for.

> What I try to achieve is to use DropZone itself to return my exist
>   images of each product and be able to remove or add to it.

I read many questions,articles, etc. And I get that I have to use `mockFile` which i have no idea about it. Would be appreciate if someone can help me to get this done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For DELETE, you could add a button next to the image that would fire the `destroy` method of the respective controller

```
@foreach($images as $test)
    <img src="{{ url('/') }}/images/{{ $test->name }}" alt="test" width="100" height="100">

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"
        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                 document.getElementById('image-{{ $test->id }}').submit();">
        DELETE
    </a>

    <form id="image-{{ $test->id }}" 
          action="{{ route('images.destroy', ['id' => $test->id]) }}"
          method="POST" style="display: none;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    </form>
@endforeach
```

and handle the deletion of image in your ImageController's `destroy` method (or your custom controller's method, make sure the method types are same)

```
public function destroy(Image $image)
{
    // Destroy the Image
    Storage::delete($image->name);

   // Redirect Back
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: something is wrong here, not sure what but i get `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` error in my console.

Comment: Could you inspect your source code and check the rendered `<a>` tag, whether it is receiving the right id?

Comment: `<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                             document.getElementById('image-28').submit();">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>`

Comment: Does the corresponding form have the same id? Try replacing `-` with an underscore

Comment: form is not printing, just it's fields.

Comment: You could inspect your source  code to check for the corresponding form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164734/discussion-between-linktoahref-and-mafortis).